# Adding if condition based on value [Python]

Tags: python, conditional-statements

So basically, I have to add one more condition to my if statement depending on the length of the list. Here's the sample code:

```
for index in indices:
            if len(phrase.split(" ")) == 1:
                if path in rang:
                    rang[path] += 1
                else:
                    rang[path] = 1
            elif len(phrase.split(" ")) == 2:
                if phrase.split(" ")[1] == parser.words[index + 1]:
                    if path in rang:
                        rang[path] += 1
                    else:
                        rang[path] = 1
            elif len(phrase.split(" ")) == 3:
                if phrase.split(" ")[1] == parser.words[index + 1] and phrase.split(" ")[2] == parser.words[index + 2]:
                    if path in rang:
                        rang[path] += 1
                    else:
                        rang[path] = 1
            else:
                if phrase.split(" ")[1] == parser.words[index + 1] and phrase.split(" ")[2] == parser.words[index + 2] and phrase.split(" ")[3] == parser.words[index + 3]:
                    if path in rang:
                        rang[path] += 1
                    else:
                        rang[path] = 1
```

Comment: I need this to go infinitely.

Comment: Please provide an example for **`indices`** variable

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are splitting the same string multiple times inside a loop: suggest split once outside the loop and assign to a variable: `phrases = phrase.split(" ")` then use that variable inside the loop

Comment: @VukMC If you want it to run infinitely, wrap it in *while True* and never *break*. That should do it

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I think by infinitely, they mean there should be infinitely many cases, for each possible length of `phrase.split(" ")`. I doubt they want the code to not terminate.

Comment: @Cardstdani indices = [i for i, word in enumerate(parser.words) if word.lower() == phrase.split(" ")[0]]

Comment: This would be easier to understand and test if you made it a [MRE] by defining all necessary variables. As-is, this can't be run on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you are trying this?

```
all(p==q for p, q in zip(phrase.split(" ")[1:], parser.words[index+1:]))
```

That should replace all the `if`/`elif`-statements.

`zip` returns a tuple of two elements, one from each list; we are then iterating this list of tuples and checking for equality of both elements; just like in your code, but without knowing/restricting about the length of the lists

You can replace your code by:

```
for index in indices:
    if len(phrase.split(" "))==1 or all(p==q for p, q in zip(phrase.split(" ")[1:], parser.words[index+1:])):
        if path in rang:
            rang[path] += 1
        else:
            rang[path] = 1
```

Comment: Why `np.all`? Builtin `all` would be more readable, avoid an unnecessary import, and also allow the square brackets around the comprehension to be removed, which would allow `all` to return early and improve performance.

Comment: @Anonymous12358 Yeah, well, this is not a PR review, right? I think you easily can get the idea how to solve the posted problem, right? ;-)

Comment: I don't quite understand what is going on here, could you please elaborate on what this piece of code actually does?